Need help on fixing tkinter error on editing tk.Entry , move button up and saving in file from gui inputs
I have a tkinter gui in Python which reads an input cfg file which looks as below:
Input cfg file 
[job1]
EXEC_PATH = /usr/path
RUNIT = echo job1
TYPES = ['schedule' , 'tumbling']  
[job2]
EXEC_PATH = /usr/path
RUNIT = echo job2
PARENTS = job1
TYPES = [ 'tumbling']
[job3]
EXEC_PATH = /usr/path
RUNIT = echo job3
PARENTS = job2

The tkinter shows the order of the jobs based on the PARENTS option defined in the config file.
Problems

I have an option menu defined on each node/job in the gui. If I consecutively click on 'Show job details' and 'Edit job details' or sometimes even on single time clicking on the menus giving below text in the right side tk.Entry box :


.!panedwindow.!frame.!frame2.!frame.!entry


After editing, in the right side tk.Entry box if I press 'Save' the edited information should be save in a cfg file in disk, which is not happening.

Can I move up the 'Validate' button just beneath where the job/node params are ended ?

Instead of a dialog box validating the input file, can I use a label with green and red text on success and failure respectively?


Below is my code :
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog, messagebox
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import configparser
import os
import subprocess

def parse():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-input_file", help="Input input file.", required=False)
    parser.add_argument("-type", help="Filter sections by types.", choices=['schedule', 'tumbling'], required=False)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    return args

class JobLevels:
    def __init__(self, input_file=None, type_filter=None):
        self.input_file = input_file
        self.type_filter = type_filter
        self.deps_dict = {}
        self.level_dict = {}
        self.visited_files = set()
        self.sections = {}

    def parse_input_file(self, input_file):
        if input_file in self.visited_files:
            return
        self.visited_files.add(input_file)

        config = configparser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
        config.optionxform = str  # Preserve case sensitivity
        config.read(input_file)

        for section in config.sections():
            if section == 'include':
                for include_file in config.options(section):
                    include_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(input_file), include_file)
                    self.parse_input_file(include_file_path)
            else:
                self.sections[section] = {}
                self.sections[section]['EXEC_PATH'] = config.get(section, 'EXEC_PATH', fallback=None)
                self.sections[section]['RUNIT'] = config.get(section, 'RUNIT', fallback=None)
                self.sections[section]['PARENTS'] = config.get(section, 'PARENTS', fallback=None)
                self.sections[section]['TYPES'] = config.get(section, 'TYPES', fallback=None)
                self.sections[section]['RATING'] = config.get(section, 'RATING', fallback='0')

    def filter_sections_by_type(self):
        if not self.type_filter:
            return

        filtered_sections = {}
        for section, attributes in self.sections.items():
            types = attributes['TYPES']
            if types:
                types_list = [type.strip() for type in types.strip('[]').split(',')]
                if self.type_filter in types_list:
                    filtered_sections[section] = attributes
            else:
                # If TYPES key is not present
                filtered_sections[section] = attributes

        self.sections = filtered_sections

    def build_deps_dict(self):
        for section, attributes in self.sections.items():
            deps = attributes['PARENTS']
            if deps:
                deps_list = [dep.strip() for dep in deps.split(',')]
                self.deps_dict[section] = deps_list

    def assign_level(self, section):
        if section not in self.level_dict:
            if section not in self.deps_dict or not self.deps_dict[section]:
                self.level_dict[section] = 0
            else:
                levels = []
                for dep_section in self.deps_dict[section]:
                    temp_level = self.assign_level(dep_section)
                    levels.append(temp_level)
                self.level_dict[section] = max(levels) + 1
        return self.level_dict[section]

    def start_proc(self):
        if self.input_file:
            self.visited_files.clear()
            self.sections.clear()
            self.deps_dict.clear()
            self.level_dict.clear()
            self.parse_input_file(self.input_file)
            self.filter_sections_by_type()
            self.build_deps_dict()
            for section in self.deps_dict:
                self.assign_level(section)

class Viewer:
    def __init__(self, root, node_order_finder):
        self.root = root
        self.node_order_finder = node_order_finder

        self.main_paned_window = ttk.PanedWindow(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
        self.main_paned_window.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.left_paned_window = ttk.PanedWindow(self.main_paned_window, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.main_paned_window.add(self.left_paned_window, weight=3)

        self.right_panel = tk.Frame(self.main_paned_window, width=200, bg="lightgray")
        self.main_paned_window.add(self.right_panel, weight=1)

        self.top_frame = tk.Frame(self.left_paned_window)
        self.left_paned_window.add(self.top_frame, weight=3)

        self.bottom_panel = tk.Frame(self.left_paned_window, height=200, bg="lightgray")
        self.left_paned_window.add(self.bottom_panel, weight=1)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.top_frame, bg="white")
        self.h_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.top_frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.v_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.top_frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.scrollable_frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)

        self.scrollable_frame.bind(
            "<Configure>",
            lambda e: self.canvas.configure(
                scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all")
            )
        )

        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.h_scrollbar.set, yscrollcommand=self.v_scrollbar.set)

        self.h_scrollbar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
        self.v_scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.type_var = tk.StringVar(value="All")
        self.create_widgets()
        self.draw_graph()

    def create_widgets(self):
        control_frame = tk.Frame(self.right_panel)
        control_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)

        type_label = tk.Label(control_frame, text="Event:")
        type_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        type_options = ["All", "schedule", "tumbling"]
        type_menu = ttk.Combobox(control_frame, textvariable=self.type_var, values=type_options)
        type_menu.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
        type_menu.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.on_type_change)

        browse_button = tk.Button(control_frame, text="Browse input File", command=self.browse_file)
        browse_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        save_button = tk.Button(control_frame, text="Save", command=self.save_input_file)
        save_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.stage_params_frame = tk.Frame(self.right_panel)
        self.stage_params_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.validate_button = tk.Button(self.right_panel, text="Validate", command=self.validate_input)
        self.validate_button.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=5, pady=5)

    def browse_file(self):
        input_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("input files", "*.input")])
        if input_file:
            self.node_order_finder.input_file = input_file
            self.node_order_finder.start_proc()
            self.draw_graph()

    def save_input_file(self):
        save_file = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".input", filetypes=[("input files", "*.input")])
        if save_file:
            config = configparser.ConfigParser()
            for section, attributes in self.node_order_finder.sections.items():
                config[section] = {k: v.get() if isinstance(v, tk.Entry) else v for k, v in attributes.items()}
            with open(save_file, 'w') as configfile:
                config.write(configfile)
            self.node_order_finder.input_file = save_file
            self.node_order_finder.start_proc()
            self.draw_graph()

    def validate_input(self):
        try:
            result = subprocess.run(['ls', self.node_order_finder.input_file], capture_output=True, text=True)
            if result.returncode == 0:
                messagebox.showinfo("Validation", "Validation successful")
            else:
                messagebox.showerror("Validation", f"Error: {result.stderr}")
        except Exception as e:
            messagebox.showerror("Validation", f"Error: {str(e)}")

    def on_type_change(self, type):
        self.node_order_finder.type_filter = self.type_var.get() if self.type_var.get() != "All" else None
        self.node_order_finder.start_proc()
        self.draw_graph()

    def draw_graph(self):
        for widget in self.scrollable_frame.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()

        self.level_frames = {}
        levels = {}
        for section, level in self.node_order_finder.level_dict.items():
            if level not in levels:
                levels[level] = []
            levels[level].append(section)

        colors = ["lightblue", "lightgreen", "lightyellow", "lightpink", "lightgray"]
        for level, nodes in sorted(levels.items()):
            level_frame = tk.Frame(self.scrollable_frame, bg=colors[level % len(colors)], bd=2, relief=tk.SOLID)
            level_frame.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=10, pady=5)
            self.level_frames[level] = level_frame

            level_label = tk.Label(level_frame, text=f"Level {level}", bg=colors[level % len(colors)], font=("Arial", 12, "bold"), anchor="w")
            level_label.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)

            for node in nodes:
                self.draw_node(level_frame, node)

    def draw_node(self, parent, node):
        level = self.node_order_finder.level_dict.get(node, 0)
        label = f'{node}({level})'
        if node in self.node_order_finder.sections:
            if self.node_order_finder.sections[node]['RATING'] == '1':
                color = 'lightblue'
            else:
                color = 'skyblue'
            fg_color = 'darkblue'

            node_label = tk.Label(parent, text=label, bg=color, fg=fg_color, font=("Arial", 10), bd=1, relief=tk.SOLID, padx=5, pady=5)
            node_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

            node_label.bind("<Button-3>", lambda type, node=node: self.show_context_menu(type, node))

    def show_context_menu(self, type, node):
        context_menu = tk.Menu(self.root, tearoff=0)
        context_menu.add_command(label="Show job details", command=lambda: self.show_stage_params(node, readonly=True))
        context_menu.add_command(label="Edit job details", command=lambda: self.show_stage_params(node, readonly=False))
        context_menu.add_command(label="Show Upward Dependency", command=lambda: self.show_upward_dependency(node))
        context_menu.add_command(label="Show Downward Dependency", command=lambda: self.show_downward_dependency(node))
        context_menu.post(type.x_root, type.y_root)
        self.root.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: context_menu.unpost())

    def show_stage_params(self, node, readonly):
        for widget in self.stage_params_frame.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()

        selected_node_label = tk.Label(self.stage_params_frame, text=f"Stage: {node}", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"))
        selected_node_label.pack(anchor="w")

        params = self.node_order_finder.sections[node]
        for param, value in params.items():
            param_frame = tk.Frame(self.stage_params_frame)
            param_frame.pack(fill=tk.X, pady=2)

            param_label = tk.Label(param_frame, text=f"{param}:")
            param_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

            param_entry = tk.Entry(param_frame)
            param_entry.insert(0, value)
            param_entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.X, expand=True)
            if readonly:
                param_entry.config(state='readonly')
            params[param] = param_entry

        if not readonly:
            add_button = tk.Button(self.stage_params_frame, text="+", command=lambda: self.add_param(node))
            add_button.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.validate_button.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=5, pady=5)

    def add_param(self, node):
        param_frame = tk.Frame(self.stage_params_frame)
        param_frame.pack(fill=tk.X, pady=2)

        param_label = tk.Entry(param_frame)
        param_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        param_entry = tk.Entry(param_frame)
        param_entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.X, expand=True)

        remove_button = tk.Button(param_frame, text="-", command=lambda: self.remove_param(param_frame))
        remove_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.stage_params_frame.params[param_label] = param_entry

    def remove_param(self, param_frame):
        param_frame.destroy()

    def show_upward_dependency(self, node):
        for widget in self.bottom_panel.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()

        selected_node_label = tk.Label(self.bottom_panel, text=f"Stage: {node}", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"))
        selected_node_label.pack(anchor="w")

        upward_deps = [dep for dep, deps in self.node_order_finder.deps_dict.items() if node in deps]
        self.display_dependencies(upward_deps, "Upward Dependencies")

    def show_downward_dependency(self, node):
        for widget in self.bottom_panel.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()

        selected_node_label = tk.Label(self.bottom_panel, text=f"Stage: {node}", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"))
        selected_node_label.pack(anchor="w")

        downward_deps = self.node_order_finder.deps_dict.get(node, [])
        self.display_dependencies(downward_deps, "Downward Dependencies")

    def display_dependencies(self, dependencies, title):
        title_label = tk.Label(self.bottom_panel, text=title, font=("Arial", 12, "bold"))
        title_label.pack(anchor="w")

        for dep in dependencies:
            dep_label = tk.Label(self.bottom_panel, text=dep, font=("Arial", 10))
            dep_label.pack(anchor="w")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse()
    job_obj = JobLevels(args.input_file, args.type)
    job_obj.start_proc()

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Job Visualization")
    app = Viewer(root, job_obj)
    root.geometry("800x600")
    root.mainloop()


Remove params[param] = param_entry from your show_stage_params function. params is a reference to self.node_order_finder.sections[node] and you fill it with tk.Entry. Ask one specific question at a time, not a list of questions.

Regarding the context menu, you will get _tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".!<path>!entry insert index text in case the parameter value is None (not text value).

@8349697 it is working, thanks. And apologies for asking a list
